# Can I say: it's been ages since I last ate in a restaurant

Tags: grammaticality

This should be correct:

> **It's ages** since I last ate in restaurant

But can I say:

> **It's (has) been** ages since I last ate in a restaurant

Comment: I tend to prefer the second one.

Comment: Only the second one is OK. You might explain your thinking on the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural sounding phrase to me (AmE) is:

> It's been ages since I last ate in a restaurant.

Since that is short for:

> It has been ages since I last ate in a restaurant.